# React mapping and componentization complexities

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapping

I'm struggling to map my repeated `<listItem>` because of the added differences between the items. They pull in different `const` and do different logic depending on which item it represents.

https://codesandbox.io/s/pj0yk6z91x

```
      <ListItem dense={this.props.dense} alignItems="flex-start">
        <ListItemText
          primary={
            <React.Fragment>
              Predicted score - <strong>4 Weeks</strong>
            </React.Fragment>
          }
          secondary={
            <React.Fragment>
              <Typography component="span" color="textPrimary">
                Predicted date{" "}
                <i
                  style={{ "font-size": "1em" }}
                  className="zmdi zmdi-calendar mx-2"
                />{" "}
                {moment(data.vulnerabilityDate)
                  .add(4, "weeks")
                  .format("MMM DD, YYYY")}
              </Typography>
            </React.Fragment>
          }
        />
        <ListItemSecondaryAction>
          <span
            style={{
              "font-size": "1rem",
              "background-color": status4WeeksColor,
              "min-width": "45px"
            }}
            className="vulnerability badge badge-primary"
          >
            {data.status4Weeks}
          </span>
        </ListItemSecondaryAction>
      </ListItem>
```

I want to map this against this:

```
const data = {
  status4Weeks: "2",
  status8Weeks: "3",
  status12Weeks: "4"
};
```

Which does not look like too much of a challenge, but I also want each to have a unique value that's not in the data payload of 4 weeks, 8, weeks, 12 weeks as titles. Also each one may have a seperate color associated to the value that I am already mapping:

```
const status4WeeksColor = COLORS[data.status4Weeks];
const status8WeeksColor = COLORS[data.status8Weeks];
const status12WeeksColor = COLORS[data.status12Weeks];
```

So needs to take into account for these which are all different in each:

```
{data.status4Weeks}
status4WeeksColor
.add(4, "weeks")
<strong>4 Weeks</strong>
```

Not sure where to begin here! help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you just have to define your data properly. You want to map an `array` of `ListItems`. Each one of those `ListItem` has a `title`, `statusWeek` and `color`, as well as the `numWeeks`.

Given so, your data should be an array of an object with those properties. for example:

```js
const data = [
{title: '4 Weeks', statusWeek: '2' , color: 'red', numWeeks: 4},
{title: '12 Weeks', statusWeek: '4' , color: 'blue', numWeeks: 12}]
```

Then, when you do

```
data.map(el => <ItemList {...el} />)
```

ItemList receives each element of the array with four `props` (color, title, status, number of weeks), so you just plug them into your component where they are needed, like (notice the props):

```js
<ListItem dense={this.props.dense} alignItems="flex-start">
        <ListItemText
          primary={
            <React.Fragment>
              Predicted score - <strong>{this.props.title}</strong>
            </React.Fragment>
          }
          secondary={
            <React.Fragment>
              <Typography component="span" color="textPrimary">
                Predicted date{" "}
                <i
                  style={{ "font-size": "1em" }}
                  className="zmdi zmdi-calendar mx-2"
                />{" "}
                {moment(data.vulnerabilityDate)
                  .add(this.props.numWeeks, "weeks")
                  .format("MMM DD, YYYY")}
              </Typography>
            </React.Fragment>
          }
        />
        <ListItemSecondaryAction>
          <span
            style={{
              "font-size": "1rem",
              "background-color": this.props.color,
              "min-width": "45px"
            }}
            className="vulnerability badge badge-primary"
          >
            {this.props.statusWeek}
          </span>
        </ListItemSecondaryAction>
</ListItem>
```

That should do the trick, is just another approach with data / props, I don't know if that works for you.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood your question, so maybe this is not what you're looking for.

The same way you built a color mapping for each of your data object values, you can create let's say an action mapping for each of your data object values. Then you can iterate over the different values of your `data` object and use the `COLOR` and `ACTION` mapping to determine what to do with your value

```
const ACTIONS = {
  '2': function () { /* do something */ },
  '3': function () { /* do something else */ },
};
```

```
{Object.values(data).map((type) => (
  <ListItem key={type}>
    <p>Predicted score: {type} weeks</p>
    <p
      style={{ backgroundColor: COLOR[type] }}
      onClick={ACTIONS[type].bind(this)}
      >
      {type}
    </p>
  </ListItem>
)}
```